# "The named parameter 'child' isn't defined." in TextButton Widget

Tags: flutter

I want to add a TextButton to my code... But my IDE is showing me, that the parameter child in die TextButton Widget isn't definded...
But in the official Flutter-Documents you add Text to a TextButton by the child parameter. This is my code:

```
Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: actions
              .map((action) => TextButton(
                    
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      foregroundColor: action.textColor ?? Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, action.popResult),
                    child: Text(action.title.toUpperCase()),
                  ))
              .toList(),
        )
```

Hope that somebody can help me with this issue.

Comment: May be problem with your IDE. If restart your IDE, also don't work?

Comment: @SulaymonNe'matov i've just changed all TextButtons to ElevatedButtons... now it works, really weird but ok, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is not in the `child` property but in the `foregroundColor` of the  `TextButton#styleFrom` function because `foregroundColor` is a property that calculates the value based on the `onSurface` or `primary` arguments and you cannot set it directly